# rails date_select title as a value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, validation

I am using date_select like so

```
<%= f.label :birthday %>
<%= f.date_select :birthday , :order => [:month, :day, :year] ,:start_year => 1900, :end_year => Time.now.year-10 %>
```

I want to have the very first options in each field to be "day" "month" and "year" and which won't be valid

How do I add these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you need custom prompts for the date fields?

Then you need to use :prompt option:

date_select("birthday", :prompt => { :day => 'day', :month => 'month', :year => 'year' })

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use one of these options for date_select?

- `:default => 3.days.from_now`
- `:include_blank => true`